# How can I detect if Office is licensed with a volume license key?

Tags: ms-office, rdp, terminal-services, office-automation

I am working on an application that uses the automation interface to work with Office documents. This application will be run on a Windows Server environment which is accessed by clients using RDP (Remote Desktop). In order for Office to work from RDP, it needs to be activated with a Terminal Services license key. If Office is not licensed in this way, I need to show an error to the user.

My question is: how can I detect if Office is activated with a Terminal Services license key? I tried using ospp.vbs and slmgr.vbs but I couldn't find a way to detect if Office is activated with a Terminal Services license.

Comment: Take a look at the [How to check the activation type and status of Office 2010 installations](http://blogs.technet.com/b/odsupport/archive/2010/08/11/how-to-check-the-activation-type-and-status-of-office-2010-installations.aspx) article. You can parse the output text and detect the type of activation key.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I believe this will work for me. In addition to the 3 types of activations listed in the article (KMS, MAK, and Retail), I have an MSDN Retail license which also works with Terminal Services. It sounds like I can assume that Office will work with Terminal Services if the license type is KMS, MAK, or MSDN.